# Opening cefsharp browser from a external html file or a link

Tags: c#, .net, windows, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I compiled the cefsharp and did a setup file from it. I installed the my custom browser on my windows 7 64 bit pc and I made my custom browser, the default browser. There is not problem until here. It runs perfectly when I run the browser.exe.

Problem is:
When I clicked a local html file or a link like that this picture([image]), The browser.exe run but cannot open, returns error. Error is "It cannot load cefsharp.dll, cefshap.core.dll ..., all cefsharp dlls"

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you copy and paste the exact error message you receive? I think you have paraphrased the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cefsharp has a bug in Cefsharp.dll while loading the dependencies. I fixed it and error gone.

While loading the dependencies some paths are absoulate. I change them into relative paths.

Comment: Feel free to open a pull request on the `CefSharp GitHub` project with your proposed changes.